# Suggestion on the hackerRank solution about alphabets and weight

Tags: haskell

I have solved the [designer pdf](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-pdf-viewer/problem) question  with haskell. The code works. I am posting the code here to know how I could have done it better.

- First line contains the weight of each alphabet
- Second line contains the word.

Sample input

```
1 3 1 3 1 4 1 3 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7
zaba
```

Output

```
28
```

explanation each character would take 1 space and multiply it with the max weight

```
4 characters * 1 space * 7 weight = 28
```

'z' has the max weight of 7.

Code

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

getintval::(Maybe Int) -> Int
getintval Nothing = 1
getintval (Just x) = x

solve'::[Char]->[(Char, Int)] -> Int
solve' ch lst = k $  map getintval $ map (\x -> finder' x) ch
  where
  k::[Int] -> Int
  k fb = (*) (length ch)   $ foldl (\acc x -> max acc x) 1 fb
  finder'::Char -> Maybe Int
  finder' g =  case i of
            Just(x1,x2) -> Just x2
            Nothing -> Just 1
            where i = find(\(val1, val2) -> val1 == g) lst


solve::[Char] -> [Char] -> Int
solve wght val = solve' val rec
  where
  rec::[(Char, Int)]
  rec = zipWith (\x y -> (x, y)) ['a'..'z'] word1
  word1::[Int]
  word1 = map(read::String->Int) $ words wght

main::IO()
main = do
  weight <- getLine
  pdfstr <- getLine
  putStr . show $ solve weight pdfstr
```

All the test on HackerRank are success

Comment: This is the question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review Q&A site.

Comment: I am not familiar with hackerRank, but their page for the Haskell version of this question looks a bit weird. The C++ version looks perfectly reasonable. Regarding your code, it might have been reinventing some pre-existing library functionality. Please let us know if you post something into [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).